# Php-cpp Call to undefined function

Tags: php, c++, php-extension

I'm using php-cpp for creating a php extension.

main.cpp

```
#include <phpcpp.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void helloWorld(Php::Parameters &params)
{
  string name = params[0];
  cout << "Hello" << name << endl;
}

extern "C" {

    /**
     *  Function that is called by PHP right after the PHP process
     *  has started, and that returns an address of an internal PHP
     *  strucure with all the details and features of your extension
     *
     *  @return void*   a pointer to an address that is understood by PHP
     */
    PHPCPP_EXPORT void *get_module()
    {
        static Php::Extension extension("yourextension", "1.0");
        extension.add("helloWorld", helloWorld);
        return extension;
    }
}
```

Then I ran $ `make && sudo make install` which outputs

```
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
cp -f yourextension.so /usr/lib/php/20151012
cp -f yourextension.ini /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d
```

Checking the php config

```
myname@ubuntu:~/EmptyExtension$ php -i | grep -i yourextension
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/yourextension.ini
yourextension
```

Seems fine for me, so I trying to use `helloWorld()`

test.php

```
<?php

echo extension_loaded('yourextension'); // outputs 1 
echo helloWorld('it works');
```

But it does not work ;)

ErrorMessage `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function helloWorld()`

Any ideas?
I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and php7.0.8

Thanks a lot

**EDIT**
When compiled php-cpp I'm getting following output, maybe there is something wrong already?

```
myname@ubuntu:~/PHP-CPP$ sudo make install
mkdir -p /usr/include/phpcpp
mkdir -p /usr/lib
cp -f phpcpp.h /usr/include
cp -f include/*.h /usr/include/phpcpp
if [ -e libphpcpp.so.2.0.0 ]; then \
    cp -f libphpcpp.so.2.0.0 /usr/lib/; \
    ln -f -s /usr/lib/libphpcpp.so.2.0.0 /usr/lib/libphpcpp.so.2.0; \
    ln -f -s /usr/lib/libphpcpp.so.2.0.0 /usr/lib/libphpcpp.so; \
fi
if [ -e libphpcpp.a.2.0.0 ]; then cp -f libphpcpp.a.2.0.0 /usr/lib/; \
    ln -f -s /usr/lib/libphpcpp.a.2.0.0 /usr/lib/libphpcpp.a; \
fi
if `which ldconfig`; then \
    sudo ldconfig; \
fi
```

**EDIT[2]**
The function seems even not to be exported

```
myname@ubuntu:~/EmptyExtension$ sudo nm -D /usr/lib/php/20151012/yourextension.so 
0000000000201060 B __bss_start
                 U __cxa_atexit
                 w __cxa_finalize
                 U __cxa_guard_abort
                 U __cxa_guard_acquire
                 U __cxa_guard_release
0000000000201060 D _edata
0000000000201130 B _end
0000000000000a6c T _fini
00000000000009c0 T get_module
                 w __gmon_start__
                 U __gxx_personality_v0
0000000000000810 T _init
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
                 U _Unwind_Resume
                 U _ZN3Php9Extension6moduleEv
                 U _ZN3Php9ExtensionC1EPKcS2_i
                 U _ZN3Php9ExtensionD1Ev
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is, to remove the compiled files because they will not get overwritten by `$ make && sudo make install`.

So `$  rm -f main.o yourextension.so && make && sudo make install` did the trick here

Answer (score 0):

First you have to run it properly. Following commands should be run to compile it.

1. make
2. sudo make install
3. make -B
4. Php test.php

You have to follow these four steps.